# jsoup - extract text from wikipedia article

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, wikipedia

I'm writing some Java code in order to realize NLP tasks upon texts using Wikipedia. How can I use JSoup to extract all the text of a Wikipedia article (for example all the text in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston)?

Comment: Is parsing the text with `jsoup` part of the interesting problem? Because if not, you should just use the `action=raw` parameter to get the source for each page. e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Elephant&action=raw

Comment: That returns the Wiki markup.

Comment: use this, it's more robust and esier on the wikipedia servers too: http://trulymadlywordly.blogspot.com/2011/03/creating-text-corpus-from-wikipedia.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston").get();
Element contentDiv = doc.select("div[id=content]").first();
contentDiv.toString(); // The result
```

You retrieve formatted content this way, of course. If you want "raw" content you can filter the result with `Jsoup.clean` or use the call `contentDiv.text()`.

Comment: Why not? It should, but it returns things like headers or enumeration bullets. If you only want (english) words you need to filter a little, but we don't know your exact requirements.

Comment: I copied your code in my class and it was not working. However I have done by myself before trying your solution...and the solution is similar!!! Thanks however...now I'm working on another issue!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160760/how-can-i-extract-specific-links-in-wikipedia-articles-using-jsoup#comment11521257_9160760

Comment: I took those lines from live code, so they should at least run.

Comment: YES THEY RUN! But however I solved the problem!!! Did u take a look to the other question?

Comment: I will be more motivated to answer that question if this one is completed. What was the problem with my solution? How did you solve the problem?

Comment: Just click on the "Help" link besides the comment box to see the syntax. If it is longer you could create an own answer.

Comment: I'm sorry? I did provide a solution, you didn't tell your problem with it.

Comment: But you ask me to put my solution and if u try it you will se that the output is a little bit different, but your solution is good!!!! It was my mistake!! The problem is that I solved by myself!!! That's all! So I need help in the other question ...not in this...but nobody is trying to help me!

Comment: Please calm down. If you don't provide any feedback (What again was the _problem_ with my code?) the motivation to help sinks rapidly. And you should show what you have done so far and where your problems are (in your other question), not just ask for people to do your job.

Answer (score 3):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements paragraphs = doc.select(".mw-content-ltr p");

    Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
    Element lastParagraph = paragraphs.last();
    Element p;
    int i=1;
    p=firstParagraph;
    System.out.println(p.text());
    while (p!=lastParagraph){
        p=paragraphs.get(i);
        System.out.println(p.text());
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston").timeout(5000);

Element iamcontaningIDofintendedTAG= doc.select("#iamID") ;

System.out.println(iamcontaningIDofintendedTAG.toString());
```

OR

```
Elements iamcontaningCLASSofintendedTAG= doc.select(".iamCLASS") ;

System.out.println(iamcontaningCLASSofintendedTAG.toString());
```