# How can I extract specific links in Wikipedia articles using jsoup?

Tags: java, hyperlink, jsoup, wikipedia, extract

I am doing an NLP project and I need to know how to extract links that only are in the "introduction" section and in the "geography" section of this wikipidia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston

Could you please help me?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151075/jsoup-extract-text-from-wikipedia-article

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe it will by simpler for you to use *Wikimedia Downloads* [Database backup dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/)

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you'll have to iterate over elements until you find another `<h3>`, indicating a section header.

Comment: @beerbajay While it's related, it's obviously not a duplicate, since this asks specifically about individual elements.

Comment: @beerbajay It is NOT a duplicate! I'd like to know how I can use the select() method to extract links from a specific section of a wikipedia article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia does not make this easy.  I don't claim this to be elegant or even very reuseable.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston").timeout(5000).get();

    Element intro = doc.body().select("p").first();
    while (intro.tagName().equals("p")) {
        //here you will get an Elements object which you can
        //iterate through to get the links in the intro
        System.out.println(intro.select("a"));
        intro = intro.nextElementSibling();
    }

    for (Element h2 : doc.body().select("h2")) {
        if(h2.select("span").size() == 2) {
            if (h2.select("span").get(1).text().equals("Geography")) {
                Element nextsib = h2.nextElementSibling();
                while (nextsib != null) {
                    if (nextsib.tagName().equals("p")) {
                        //here you will get an Elements object which you
                        //can iterate through to get the links in the 
                        //geography section
                        System.out.println(nextsib.select("a"));
                        nextsib = nextsib.nextElementSibling();
                    } else if (nextsib.tagName().equals("h2")) {
                        nextsib = null;
                    } else {
                        nextsib = nextsib.nextElementSibling();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!! I tried your code and for the introduction section is working fine...I can't say the same for the geography section: some links are missed and some are from climate section! But is a good step anyway! Thanks you very much, please let me know if you found a solution! I will do the same! :)

Comment: I moved the line nextsib = nextsib.nextElementSibling(); below System.out.println(nextsib.select("a"));  That should fix it.

Comment: mmm...I think it's the same !!! Now I understand what is missed!! The links included at the beginning of Geography section (the first paragraph of Geography).

Comment: Hey sorry the first version is working!!! It was my mistake...Now Im checking with other page from wikipedia!

Comment: So...I saw that your code works with some articles like Boston, Massachusetts, New England but not with London! I will try to understand why! :) Thanks again

Comment: It will only work if the articles are laid out the same.  Wikipedia makes screen scraping like this pretty tough because they don't break sections apart and use ids and classes on the elements which would make using select much easier.  Also, the articles don't have to follow the exact same format so any deviation will break the code.

Comment: Specifically in the London case, the first <p> tag is something pointing to post codes.  Its more like the third or fourth <p> tag that holds the introduction.  Also, the <h2> tags only have one <span> within them, whereas the Boston article has two <span> tags.  Strange.

Comment: Inserting this line: 
Element intro = doc.select("table.infobox + p").first();

instead od this one:
 Element intro = doc.body().select("p").first();
made the trick! :D

Thank you a lot anyway :)