# Reading only the relevant text from an HTML page using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Is there a way to access only the textual content on Wikipedia using R. Something equivalent to jSoup as shown in this post on stack [Extraction of text using: Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151075/jsoup-extract-text-from-wikipedia-article)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/htmltotext-extracting-text-from-html-via-xpath/):

```
# load packages
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

# download html
html <- getURL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page", followlocation = TRUE)

# parse html
doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//p", xmlValue)
cat(paste(plain.text, collapse = "\n"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for.